# UITests: UINavigationBar popped from the stack still exists

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I have `UINavigationController` with 3 controllers:

- **the roor**

[image]

```
let wishlistsNavigationBar = app.navigationBars["wishlistsNavigationBar"]
```

- **account**

[image]

```
let accountNavigationBar = app.navigationBars["accountNavigationBar"]
```

- **add**

[image]

```
let addWishlistNavigationBar = app.navigationBars["addWishlistNavigationBar"]
```

Now I perform the tests:

```
accountButton.tap()
XCTAssertTrue(accountNavigationBar.exists) //true

backFromAccountButton.tap()
XCTAssertFalse(accountNavigationBar.exists) //true, test failed, but it should not exists
XCTAssertTrue(wishlistsNavigationBar.exists) //false, test failed, but it should exists
```

Let's see. Why there still exists `accountNavigationBar` since I pop it from stack?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the ViewController is animated, have you tried to wait a few seconds for it to disappear instead of instantly testing after tapping the button? For instance, you could try

```
expectationForPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1"), evaluatedWithObject: accountNavigationBar, handler: nil)
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(defaultPredicateTestTimeout, handler: nil)
```